# Injeção de dependência com Ninject para mais de um projeto web

Tags: asp.net-mvc, injeção-de-dependência, asp.net-web-api, ninject

Olá, em uma aplicação eu tenho um projeto web MVC e uma projeto Web API, no proejto MVC eu já tenho o Ninject configurado com as injeções de dependências e eu gostaria de aproveitá-lo neste projeto Web API, eu sei que talvez terei que separá-lo em um projeto para para injeção de dependência para poder referência-lo nos dois projetos, mas a minha duvida é de como fazer isso.

Alguém saberia me dizer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar Mudules como explica na documentação:

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Modules-and-the-Kernel

Basicamente você cria um Module em uma DLL a parte, como isto:

```
public class WarriorModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load() 
    {
        Bind<IWeapon>().To<Sword>();
        Bind<Samurai>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
    }
}
```

E chama em ambos os projetos (MVC e Web Api):

```
 IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new WarriorModule());

 IDependency dependency = kernel.Get<IDependency>();
```

Comment: Só para esclarecer Fernando, fazendo isso eu teria que configurar o Ninject nos dois projetos, MVC e WebAPI, e carregaria o modulo nos dois?

Comment: Exato, a "configuração" é minimamente duplicada, mas o módulo é compartilhado.